# Upload a file using Drag and Drop on the Browse button in the Browser

Tags: gwt, file-upload, smartgwt

We are using file upload from the gwt but i want to upload the file by drag and drop in the browser. It is working fine with chrome browser but not working with Firefox because in Chrome it is showing choose File and Firefox it is showing Browse option. How can i upload the file in the Firefox browser by Drag and drop?

We are using GWT 2.5.1 and Smart Gwt 4.1.
We could do the drag and drop in any version of chrome but not in any version of firefox browser.

Code Snippet:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.smartgwt.client.types.Alignment;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Label;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.DynamicForm;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.FileItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextItem;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.HLayout;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class TestApp implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        VLayout vTest=new VLayout();
        vTest.setBackgroundColor("#D3D3D3");

        VLayout fileVLayout = new VLayout(10);
        fileVLayout.setAutoWidth();
        fileVLayout.setAutoHeight();
        fileVLayout.setPadding(10);
        final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();

        TextItem filename = new TextItem();
        filename.setTitle("File Name");
        TextItem uploader = new TextItem();
        uploader.setTitle("uploader name");
        uploader.setWrapTitle(false);


        **// Smart GWT** 
        final FileItem uploadfile = new FileItem();
        uploadfile.setTitle("File Item");
        uploadfile.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);

        **// GWT** 
        final FileUpload fileTest = new FileUpload();
        fileTest.setTitle("File Upload");

        form.setItems(filename, uploader, uploadfile);
        form.draw();

        HLayout fileHLayout = new HLayout(10);
        fileHLayout.setHeight(10);
        Label fileNameStaticLabel = new Label();
        fileNameStaticLabel.setContents("File Upload");
        fileNameStaticLabel.setWrap(false);
        fileNameStaticLabel.setHeight("25px");
        fileNameStaticLabel.setAlign(Alignment.RIGHT);

        fileVLayout.addMember(form);
        fileHLayout.addMember(fileNameStaticLabel);
        fileHLayout.addMember(fileTest);

        vTest.addMember(fileVLayout);
        vTest.addMember(fileHLayout);

        RootPanel.get().add(vTest);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are too little information for us to answer your question. What gwt version? Browser Versions? What components do you use? Some Code?

Comment: Hello @Charmin , I have added the code and required inforamtion, please look into my above query.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just replace the native GWT code with Smart GWT code.

You are mixing GWT with Smart GWT components.  You should not do that, per http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aMix.  "The reason for this is that there are limits to the maximum degree that two Ajax widget kits
(including GWT) can interoperate..."

Smart GWT has its own file picker, see http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html (FileItem).  And also it's own Canvas system:  Don't use GWT RootPanel, use Smart GWT Canvas or VLayout, etc.

Though Smart GWT has "GWT" in the name, and though it uses substantial portions of GWT (GWT Compiler, etc), Smart GWT really is a framework unto itself.  Aside from rare cases (e.g., login page), it's not advisable to mix Smart GWT with native GWT.